# Cogwheel / Gear button does not work on manage display pages on Drupal 8

Tags: ajax

[image: Picture to the problem]

I am new to Drupal and having some issues with the cogwheel button on all of content types when I want to manage their display. When I click the gear / cogwheel icon "please wait" message shows up for a second then then nothing happens, no options to change. I saw this log (not Drupal log, it does not shows up any logs related to this issue) below. (Using Drupal 8.9.5 with PHP 7.4.9 and 5.5.5-10.3.23-MariaDB)

```
16212958669271217639 xx.x8.xx.6x 8x 1xx.0.x.1 8x
--23480000-B--
POST /admin/structure/types/manage/urun/display?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2520
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
Cookie: SESS5c14c0f7969f78d79c3fd3c7b705bf82=ENk2-oEjAYvOOg32skVHKKWcA6DPRgwPwOSP7w-bVXo
Host: xxxxxxx.com.tr
Referer: http://xxxxxxx.com.tr/admin/structure/types/manage/urun/display
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.x8.xx.6x Safari/537.36 OPR/70.x.xxx8.1xx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: http://xxxxxxx.com.tr

--23480000-F--
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

--23480000-H--
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 1). Match of "rx ^%{tx.allowed_request_content_type_charset}$" against "TX:1" required. [file "C:\/Program Files (x86)/Plesk/ModSecurity/rules/modsecurity_crs-plesk/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "944"] [id "920480"] [msg "Request content type charset is not allowed by policy"] [data "utf-8"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.2.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/CONTENT_TYPE_CHARSET"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-20"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/EE2"] [tag "PCI/12.1"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 1)
Apache-Handler: IIS
Stopwatch: 1599818735740733 0 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1599818735740733 0; combined=0, p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=0, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for IIS (STABLE)/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/3.2.0.
Server: ModSecurity Standalone
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--23480000-Z--

--23480000-A--
<< Less
```

UPDATE:

Error on JS console

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST https://xxxxxxx.com.tr/admin/structure/types/manage/urun/display?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax 403
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.ajaxSubmit @   jquery.form.min.js:22
Drupal.Ajax.eventResponse   @   ajax.js:332
(anonymous) @   ajax.js:271
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Another Error Message

```
ajax.js:506 Uncaught Drupal.AjaxError {message: "↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 40…r page using the credentials that you supplied.
↵", name: "AjaxError"}message: "↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 403↵Debugging information follows.↵Path: /admin/structure/types/manage/urun/display?ajax_form=1↵StatusText: error↵ResponseText: 
↵403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
↵Server Error
↵403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
↵You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
↵"name: "AjaxError"__proto__: Error
    at https://xxxxxxx.com.tr/core/misc/ajax.js?v=8.9.5:100:32
    at https://xxxxxxx.com.tr/core/misc/ajax.js?v=8.9.5:643:3
Drupal.Ajax.error @ ajax.js:506
complete @ ajax.js:241
t.complete @ jquery.form.min.js:22
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
l @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.min.js:22
Drupal.Ajax.eventResponse @ ajax.js:332
(anonymous) @ ajax.js:271
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Full Error Text

```
"
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/types/manage/urun/display?ajax_form=1
StatusText: error
ResponseText: 
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
Server Error
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
"
```

Comment: Does it work with JS disabled? Did you check file permissions on Drupal folder? JS Agreggation under Configuration > Development? What does WordPress have to do with your Drupal installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a full day's work, I found a solution described below.

It looks like an issue caused by firewall policies on the server. Fortunately, I have an App on my server called 'Web Application Firewall' where you change the settings to somehow bypass this security check.

Read through the app's manual and find the security rule ID and add it to the appropriate text area below and hit apply. This will switch off the security rule causing the issue according to the ID you found.

App's Manual

> ModSecurity audit log The ModSecurity audit log file is the most
> useful piece of information in the system. When ModSecurity detects
> that any event occurs, it generates an entry in the audit log file.
>
> A website can stop functioning as expected after you change the web
> application firewall mode to On from Off or Detection only. In this
> case, analyze the ModSecurity audit log to find out what is happening.
> You can switch off too restrictive security rules or adjust the
> website.
>
> To find out why an HTTP request cannot be completed for a website:
>
> Click the ModSecurity Log File link below and open the audit log in a
> new browser window. Use Search (Ctrl+F in most web browsers) to find
> events for the website (the domain name) that experiences problems.
> For example, your_domain.tld. The browser will highlight entries like
> HOST: your_domain.tld. In three lines above the highlighted entry,
> find a string like --eece5138-B--. The eight symbols between hyphens
> (in our example, eece5138) are the ID of the event triggered by the
> HTTP request. Search further for other entries with the same event ID.
> Look for an entry with the letter H after the event ID (in our
> example, eece5138-H--). This entry contains the ID and description of
> the security rule triggered while checking the HTTP request. The
> security rule ID is an integer number starting with 3, in quotation
> marks, and put with the prefix id in square brackets. For example, [id
> "340003"]. Find a security rule ID in the event using a substring [id
> "3. Switch off the security rule with this ID in the Security rules
> section below: enter the security rule ID (digits only) into the
> Security rule IDs field and click OK.

[image: Screenshot of ModSecurity]